# Measuring the energy of particles?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, speed-of-light, momentum, relativity

If i have the momentum of the particle, could I measure their energy ? I'm talking about particles in a beam, they are moving in a relativistic speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relativistic expression for the total energy of a particle is:

$$ E^2 = p^2c^2 + m^2c^4 $$

where $m$ is the rest mass and $p$ is the relativistic momentum:

$$ p = \gamma mv = \frac{mv}{\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}} $$

So you will need to know the mass as well as the momentum to calculate the energy. Having said this, if the particles are highly relativistic i.e. $\gamma \gg 1$ then the rest mass term can be ignored and we get:

$$ E \approx pc $$